# How to install TIxati on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mavericks, osx-yosemite

I want to install Tixati on my Mac OS X. Is there a way to do so using linux binaries available on their site? I tried doing so, but Hard luck

Answer (score 1):

From their homepage they are only delivering binaries for Windows and Linux: no OS X version. You might be able to run it in a virtual machine with Linux (or Windows if you have a Windows license).

Comment: Thats only my issue dude. I know i can run that in a VM but i want to run it solely on osx. is there a way to install that binary in osx?

Comment: @AkarshSatija No if the application was not build for OS you will not be able to run it natively.